# Qt - Camera Example not work, error not found Camera

Tags: c++, qt

The camera example provided in the qt documentation is not working, returning the following erro:

> defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for -
>   "org.qt-project.qt.camera"

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Note: I have webcam embedded in my notebook

Note: I'm using qt 5.7

Comment: execute this: `sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins`

Comment: I executed the command but the problem continues

Comment: execute: `ldd your_executable` y show the output

Comment: Output:  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9d3b9000)
 libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5 => /home/usuario/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5 (0x00007f5c3dbb9000)
 libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => /home/usuario/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Multimedia.so.5 (0x00007f5c3d8ac000)
 libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/usuario/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f5c3d05b000)
 libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/usuario/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f5c3c8cf000)
 libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/usuario/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f5c3c1b1000)

Comment: Qt 5.6 or Qt 5.7??

Comment: I have previously reported wrong, I am using qt 5.7

Comment: I noticed that you installed qt with the installer offline and you did not use apt-get. When you use the offline installer you have to activate all the modules that you are going to use, I recommend that you activate them all if you are a beginner.

Comment: Also install the gstreamer package

Comment: Or else you can install qt5 with apt-get: `sudo apt-get install qt5 qtcreator qt5-base`

Comment: I was reading about the gstreamer, I'll try to install it

Comment: install : `libgstreamer1.0-dev
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
libgstreamermm-1.0-dev`